# How to dynamically get participants when implementing skype button with url?

Tags: arraylist, skype, skypedeveloper, skype-uri.js

I am trying to add skype uri button to my web applocation. T
Skype has provided to add skype button on the website. https://www.skype.com/en/developer/create-contactme-buttons/
 However, I want to add dynamic users/participants in the script.  Please help me if you can do that.

Comment: Please keep noted that Skype for Consumer (SfC) which can be downloaded for free isn´t the same as Skype for Business (SfB) which is mostly used by companies. So I adjusted your question and removed the SfB tag as this isn´t related here.

Comment: Thanks for your edit and comment. @Bastian